# How do you translate a subordinate clause, introduced by a negation?

Tags: translation, negation, subordinate-clauses

I want to translate *The choice of *confectus* for continue seeks to convey the function of the control structure, not the literal meaning of the English word.*

To translate the last clause introduced by not, I would begin by first targeting something that would rather translate *instead of the literal meaning…*, which I would render with something like *pefere ol la laŭvorta traduko de Angla*.

First, is this approach fine?

Secondly, is there a valid way to translate that in a more direct manner like "*, ne la laŭvortan signifon de Angla vorto*"?

Answer (score 2):

*perefe ol* or *prefere al*?

My preference would be for your final suggestion, but remember it's still the object of convey:

- *ne la laŭvortan signifon de Angla vorto*

Comment: I did have some doubt about ol/al. As it's a comparative I would tend to say *ol*, but as it's also can be thought as an (non-)target, *al* seems also relevant.

Comment: Both *al* and *ol* are used. I'm assuming, though that "perefe" is a typo.

Comment: Yes, indeed, in fact I didn't even noticed the typo in your answer. ^^

Answer (score 2):

I think "ne" works well to introduce subordinate clauses. "Prefere" has a different nuance. Compare:

- Mi volas la pomon, ne la piron.
  (If you can't have the apple, you'd have nothing, because you don't want the pear.)
- Mi volas la pomon, prefere ol la piron. 
  (Here, you'd prefer the apple, but could consider the pear if the apple is not avaliable.)

It works the same with longer clauses:

- Mi volas ĝuste tiun ĉemizon, ne ajnan ĉemizon kiun vi aĉetis en la vendejo.